# Rails: in a nested model form the children attributes are not reflected on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the revised version of the nested models Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

I have a similar form, the railscast uses the models survey, question, answer; but I have member, child and caregiver instead.

My code is almost exactly the same as the railscast. I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.2.

My problem is, the children attributes are not reflected on the form. According to this: http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes There is no need to do anything on the controller...

> The beauty of this solution is that it takes your controllers out of
>   the mix and makes standard for submissions work perfectly with no
>   interference at the controller level.

If I don't do this `@member.children << Child.new` the nested children part of the form does not appear.

```
def new
  @member = Member.new
  @member.children << Child.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still need to have children records for the model in order for the form to see it
i would change your controller a bit to use build instead of adding to array

```
def new
  @member = Memeber.new
  @member.children.build
end
```